# Que veut dire l'expression, utilisée à l'oral: "Stainbeu", au Québec

Tags: expressions, oral, québec

Note: J'écris "au Québec" dans le titre, mais c'est peut-être plus régional que le Québec au complet je ne le sais pas. J'habite en Mauricie.

Exemple d'utilisation;

> Hey *stènebeu* qu'il n'écoute pas aujourd'hui!

Il m'arrive souvent d'entendre cette expression, et non pas seulement entre connaissance, mais à la télé aussi dans des émissions d'ici. Il se veut un remplacement aux fameux "sacres" et peut se remplacer par d'autres mots utilisés comme patois au Québec. Il semblerait qu'on l'utilise majoritairement à exprimer l'étonnement, le découragement. Je crois cependant qu'on l'entend de moins en moins, car je remarque que c'est surtout les personnes d'une cinquantaine d'années et plus qui semblent l'utiliser.

Il faut le lire comme on le dit et non pas au sens litéraire: stènebeu, stainebeu... je ne sais pas exactement comment l'écrire.

Je m'essaie avec les sons à prononcer mais je ne m'y connais pas tout a fait;
`[stɛ̃bø]`

**Ma question**
D'où vient cette expression et que veut-elle dire exactement?

Je me pose toujours des questions sur les expressions car, à titre d'exemple, je sais maintenant ce que veut dire "dégédine" et je ne l'utilise plus maintenant.

> Définition Déguédine: Les prostituées jadis, pour presser le client anglais, disaient "Dig it in" ce qui veut dire "Enfonce-la". C'est devenu "déguédine".

Exemple: Enwoye déguédine!

Comment: Est-ce que tu entends la nasale /stɛ̃/ ou /stœ̃/ par hasard (ou avec les dipthongues)?

Comment: C'est plutôt `/stɛ̃/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cette expression s'écrit en réalité "**Ostin d'beu**" (ou "ostin d'beux").

Elle aurait été inventée par Guy Fournier, le créateur de la série télévisée [*Jamais deux sans toi*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamais_deux_sans_toi_(s%C3%A9rie_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9e)) à la fin des années 1970 (1977-1980), pour remplacer les "sacres" et donner à ses personnages un vocabulaire unique. Cette série datant de plus de 40 ans, on comprend tout à fait pourquoi les personnes qui emploient cette expression ont plus de 50 ans : elle est ancrée dans leur culture.

Pour en savoir plus sur les expressions inventées par Guy Fournier, je recommande [cet article](https://www.journaldemontreal.com/2015/02/20/en-francais-sil-vous-plait) écrit par lui-même. D'autres mots de "patois mémorable" sont disponibles [ici](https://www.envedette.ca/tops/les-patois-memorables-de-nos-personnages-quebecois-preferes-1.2601249).

Quant à l'étymologie exacte du mot, [des membres du forum WordReference s'y sont essayés](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ostin-dbeu.466310/) sans grand succès. Il semblerait que ce soit simplement un juron de type "Mince !".